# Accept stdin in Electron-Main process on Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, stdin, stdio

I've tried setting `ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE=true` and studied every source and example on the web I can find, but I've not found a way to get true `stdio` on Electron. Getting it with a plain Node application is no problem.

Unfortunately for my use case, Chrome Native Messaging, the process that accepts `stdio` must be the same process that Chrome reaches out to initiate, which makes simply passing it off to a child process impossible as far as I can tell. I'd be open to a method using a child process if it doesn't need to open a new executable file.

[There's one example of a way to use `stdio` indirectly here](https://gist.github.com/stelcheck/a0c798ff31df5f2c0e5d72513948dcf1), but I don't think it can work with Electron. I'd be very glad to be wrong.

[This is a relevant, though rather old discussion on Electron accepting `stdin` on Windows](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4218#issuecomment-174455758)